# spinner-menu с невидимым результатом выбора

Tags: java, android

делаю меню на спинере, но надо так, чтобы выбранное значение вызывало действие (в том числе и запуск новой Activity) и не отображалось в голове списка. С действием все понятно, и отображением - сделал с помощью setVisibility, но в тех случаях когда список открывается, но выбор не делается (клик в сторону), похоже событие не происходит и видимость предыдущего выбора  запретить не удается, то, что раньше удачно запрещалось появляется.  Список открываю отдельной кнопкой. может кто-то знает как не показывать выбранное значение. Может какое-то свойство или метод?

Всем кто прочитал и хотел помочь - *Большое спасибо*.
Я решил проблему, но это трюковый способ.
Добавил еще одно значение в массив списка, состоящее из пробелов и каждое событие спиннера завершал выбором этого значения: **adapterView.setSelection(6);**
(В моем случае строка пробелов это шестой элемент массива. Таким образом если значение и появлялось, то оно состояло из одних пробелов.

Comment: если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, то его надо оформить ответом (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос") а не писать решение в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не отображалось выбранное значение добавил еще один элемент падающего списка (в данном случае шестой элемент списка), который состоит из пробелов - именно он оказывается в заголовке списка во всех случаях. 
Добавил слtдующие обработчики:

```
//Кнопку, при нажатии на которую список разворачивается:
  public void but_open(android.view.View view){
  spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  spinner.performClick();
}


//Обработчик выбора элемента списка:    
  @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent;

    switch (i){
        case 0:{
            intent=new Intent(SaleActivity.this,ECRActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }break;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        case 5:{
            intent=new Intent(SaleActivity.this,ServiceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }break;
        case 6:{

        }break;
    }
    //а на место выбранного элемента подставляется шестой, состоящий из пробелов
    adapterView.setSelection(6);
    adapterView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}

//Обработчик, когда ни один элемент не выбран
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    adapterView.setSelection(6);
    adapterView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}
```